# What is a node name? how do i rename it? Oracle Database Client

Tags: database, oracle, installation, oracle12c, nodename

I've been trying to install Oracle Database Client 12c and no matter what settings i select, i keep getting the error:

PRVG-11322 : One or more node names "px_dev004" contain one or more of the following invalid characters "_"

before the installation begins. is there a way i can rename the node names or work around this problem?

Comment: Is `px_dev004` the name of the machine you're installing on? [RFC-952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt) (and a slight relaxation in [RFC-1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)) doesn't allow underscores in Internet host names; your host (node) might not be on the internet or in DNS but even so having a name like that is questionable. Oracle's prerequisite checks clearly don't like it. You might be able to skip that check with the command line flag, but it might still cause you problems later.

Comment: I think px_dev004 is the name of my machine but im not 100% sure. The reason for installing this is so i can connect win automation to an oracle database and insert data through win automation. could you tell me how to skip the check via the command line? what type of problems might this cause later?

Comment: Depends where it's stopping; there are flags to skip prerequisite and system checks. Or through OUI I think it gives you the option to ignore errors. Not sure what you mean by 'win automation', but maybe the instant client will do what you need? That is much simpler to install.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. It is to install the 11g version which didn't have the prerequisite check for _ in a name.

Comment: However this will make it impossible to use any 12c features that require a 12c client.